# NDBCluster LOAD DATA Infile performance

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to load some data into a MySQL cluster. The cluster has 5 VMs total, 8 GB of RAM each, all running CentOS and MySQL Cluster 7.2.5. All 5 VMs are on the same physical blade so the network bottleneck between them should be minimal. Here's a pastebin of my [config.ini](http://pastebin.com/JhrjdXKH), and another of my [my.cnf](http://pastebin.com/9y1mY7zm). I'm limited to two links so I can't paste the table schema but basically it has mostly int columns and a couple of text columns. The primary key is a composite key on one bigint and one int.

The data file I'm loading in is 129MB total, and I'm getting speeds of about 150 rows/second which is just abysmal. I'm going to have to do this on a much larger scale and at this rate it could take days to load. Are there any parameters I should be tweaking to dramatically speed this up? I've found similar threads about parameters to tune for myisam and innodb bulk loading, but haven't seen any about NDB tables.

Here's the load data infile command:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

When I run the same exact command but change the engine of the table to innodb, it loads 20,000 rows per second instead of 150 rows per second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL Cluster is a different beast partitioning all your data across multiple nodes.

You can load into Innodb first, see: http://johanandersson.blogspot.co.nz/2012/04/mysql-cluster-how-to-load-it-with-data.html

In short:

Increase the ndb batch size (if you know what you are doing, I haven't tried it) and use multiple connections

```
SET ndb_batch_size=8*1024*1024;
```

On every table

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=ndbcluster;
```

And finally

```
ANALYZE TABLE tablename;
```